# Can I catch the error in MediaPlayer if file not available at the link

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

I am starting mediaplayer with a URL. The URL suppose to link to a video/Audio . But i have deleted the video/audio file from the location, hence i would like to expect a IOException id there is nothing available at that link.

But i am not getting the IO exception. Instead mediaplayer itself try to go to the linkl 10 times and finally throw the error on onErrorListner. follwings are the logs printed while mediaPlayer is preparing.

Comment: Include the code that you have done so far.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you have tried and what code you are using, otherwise it’s very difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to **connect to that location first**. If there was an error then this will be your `Exception`.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
URL u = new URL(params[0]);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = null;
if (conn.getResponseCode() == 404) {
is = conn.getErrorStream();// File not found
} else if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
is = getInputStream(); // It's there
}
}
```

Comment: Skillson thanks for your reply i appreciate but my problem is that media player retry to load the url 10 times if there is no file available at that url and it is taking too much time to give the error response i want to catch error on first or second retry